# How to fix the syntax error about ";" of jQuery code below

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fade in and fade out one button in my web page using jQuery library. The problem is that the code below is not executing because of some syntax errors.

```
$(document).ready(y);

var y=function(){
  $('div').mouseenter(z);
  $('div').mouseleave(a);
};

var z=function(){
  $('div').fadeTo('fast',1);
};

var a=function(){
  $('div').fadeTo('fast',0.5);
};
```

Should anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Fix the syntax errors? Although the code you've posted does not have any syntax errors... just incorrect invocation order.

Comment: y is undefined.

Comment: Declare y function first. You got UNDEFINED on assigning.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9onm4fw9/

Comment: Also, you should use jQuery chaining on your `y` function.

Answer (score 2):

Variable and functions gets hosted to the top
this

```
$(document).ready(y);

var y = function(){
  $('div').mouseenter(z);
  $('div').mouseleave(a);
};
```

becomes like this when parsed by the browser

```
var y = undefined
$(document).ready(y); // undefined

// redefines y
y = function(){
  $('div').mouseenter(z);
  $('div').mouseleave(a);
};
```

so declering y first or chage it to a function helps

```
$(document).ready(y); // function

function y(){
  $('div').mouseenter(z);
  $('div').mouseleave(a);
};
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for letting me know that variable y must be declared at the top :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

I feel like you are doing an awful lot of work to fade in/out a button, try this instead?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#button_id').fadeIn(1000);
      $('#button_id').fadeOut(1000);

      //fade in/out on the button click
      $('#button_id').click(function(){
            $('#button_id').fadeIn(1000);
            $('#button_id').fadeOut(1000);
      });

      //the value parse into the fade methods will execute the animation over 1 second
});
```

Comment: lol @MikeMcCaughan this *has* syntax errors. The original code just didn't work.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yeah, part of the joke ;)